# Tengo un error en el código "this.lista = this.deseosService.obtenerLista( listaId );"

Tags: javascript, typescript, vscode

//En el "this.lista" hay un error que dice "El tipo 'void' no se puede asignar al tipo 'Lista'."
// En el "listaId" del "this.lista" también esta el error "No se puede asignar un argumento de tipo "string | null" al parámetro de tipo "string | number".
El tipo 'null' no se puede asignar al tipo 'string | number'."

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Lista } from 'src/app/models/lista.model';
import { DeseosService } from 'src/app/services/deseos.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-agregar',
  templateUrl: './agregar.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./agregar.page.scss'],
})
export class AgregarPage {


  lista: Lista;

   constructor(private deseosService: DeseosService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { 

    const listaId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('listaId');


      this.lista = this.deseosService.obtenerLista( listaId ); 

  }

}
```

//------"lista" esta definido acá -------//

```
 import { ListaItem } from "./lista-item-model";



export class Lista {


    id: number;
    titulo: string;
    creadaEn: Date;
    terminadaEn: any;
    terminada: boolean;
    items: ListaItem[];

    constructor( titulo: string ){
    
        this.titulo = titulo;

        this.creadaEn = new Date();
        this.terminada = false;
        this.items = [];

        this.id = new Date().getTime();
    }
}
```

//---------este es el codigo de "src/app/services/deseos.service"--------//

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Lista } from '../models/lista.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DeseosService {

  listas: Lista [] = [];

  constructor() { 

    this.cargarStorage();

  }

  crearLista( titulo: string ){

    const nuevaLista = new Lista(titulo);
    this.listas.push( nuevaLista );
    this.guardarStorage();

    return nuevaLista.id;

  }

  obtenerLista( id: string | number ){

    id = Number(id);

    this.listas.find( listaData => {
      return listaData.id === id;    
    });
  }

  guardarStorage(){

    localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(this.listas));

  }

  cargarStorage(){
    const lista = localStorage.getItem('data');
    if( lista){
      this.listas = JSON.parse(lista);
    }  

  }

}
```

Comment: Falta que muestres el código de `src/app/services/deseos.service`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes 2 problemas:

1.- `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('listaId')` puede entregar un valor nulo o string tal como lo indica la [documentación](https://docs.angular.lat/api/router/ParamMap)

Entonces tu tienes:

```
const listaId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('listaId');
```

donde listaId será del tipo `null | string`, en cambio tu función `obtenerLista` acepta como argumento el tipo `string | number`.

2.- El otro problema es que obtenerLista no está retornando algo, es decir es vacio `void`

Para corregir el primer problema basta con agregar el `null` como un posible tipo del argumento de la función y el segundo problema se resuelve con agregar `return`

```
obtenerLista( id: string | number | null){

  id = Number(id);
  return this.listas.find( listaData => listaData.id === id);
}
```

Llegado a este punto te encuentras con un par de dilemas:

- Si `id==null` entonces al convertirlo a número es cero, ya que `Number(null)==0`
- Que el `id` ingresado no exista en el `array`, entonces el `find` retornará `undefined`

Este es un problema muy comun en la programación. Tu podrias simplemente retornar `null` o `undefined` para estos casos y hacer que `lista` acepte esos tipos -> `lista: Lista | null | undefined;` pero esto solo arrastra el problema y eventualmente en algún lado debes validarlo. Otra forma sería arrojar una excepción, algo así:

```
obtenerLista( id: string | number | null) : Lista {
 if(id == null) throw new Error("Id es nulo");

 id = Number(id);
 let resp = this.listas.find( listaData => listaData.id === id);

 if(resp) return resp;

 throw new Error("Item no está en el array");
}
```

Y luego en AgregarPage

```
  lista: Lista;

  constructor(private deseosService: DeseosService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { 

    const listaId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('listaId');

    try{
      this.lista = this.deseosService.obtenerLista( listaId ); 
    }
    catch(err){
       console.error(err);
       //Aquí tomas acciones para alertar que ha ocurrido un problema, puede ser un mensaje al usuario
    }
}
```

Comment: Agregue lo que me dijiste. Ahora me tira error en el "this.lista" que dice 

"El tipo 'Lista | never[] | undefined' no se puede asignar al tipo 'Lista'.
  El tipo 'undefined' no se puede asignar al tipo 'Lista'."

Comment: @MisaelDuré cuando llamas a la función `obtenerLista` que es lo que esperas obtener: alternativas (1) Un solo objeto del tipo lista o (2) un array de objetos ???

Comment: Creo que un objeto tipo lista. Perdón mi ignorancia, estoy aprendiendo jsjs

Comment: @MisaelDuré He editado la respuesta, espero esto te ayude

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!
Ya esta funcionando!!